# What are the drawbacks of the Facade design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, aop, aspects, facade

…and how can we overcome them using the aspect-oriented programming?

Answer (score 5):

There is really **no known drawbacks to [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)**. It provides a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. However, it does not ab ovo prevent clients from using the subsystem interfaces directly. So you are not forced to make any unwanted compromises with it. It is a win-win situation.

Maybe we can give you a better answer if you add more details to your question. What drawbacks do you mean, and where did you get the idea that Facade has drawbacks? And **what is "aspect oriented Facade design pattern"?** The only page Google serves to this query is in fact your own post :-/

Comment: [Ab ovo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_ovo), really! :)